# How to use cloudfront for path based routing between ec2 and amplify with the same domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have an API on a AWS ec2 instance with the route `domain.com/api`. And I have deployed a NextJS app on amplify which I want to show on the home page of my `domain.com`. How to use cloudfront to distinguish between the two and send resources accordingly?

I have managed to set up CloudFront but it is throwing an `access denied` error. I have set up a load balancer for my EC2 instance also. What might be wrong here?

The API on ec2 and the app on amplify is working independently. I have checked them both.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to get through?